# Prove a function is continuous

Tags: real-analysis

> Discuss the continuity of the function $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$
>   if
>
> $f(x) = 0$ if $x$ is not rational
>
> $f(x) = \frac1q$ if $x = \frac{p}{q}$ where $p,q$ are integers with no
>   common divisors other than $\pm 1$.

I know that the function  is not continuous so I must show that for every $\epsilon>0$ there exists $\delta >0$ such that if $x\in \mathbb{R}$ and $|x-x_0|<\delta$ then $|f(x) -f(x_0)|>\epsilon$, for some $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}$ but I don't know how to show this.

Comment: You don't "Prove a continuous function," you prove a function is continuous.

Comment: By the way, this is called [Thomae's function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomae%27s_function)

Comment: @Tyler I have made the edit.

Comment: That is not the negation of the definition of continuity.  When you negate a statement, 'for all's turn into 'there exists's, and vice versa.  So, *there exists* an $\varepsilon > 0$ such that *for all* $\delta > 0$ ...

Comment: Plz, look that... [http://www.math.washington.edu/~morrow/334_10/thomae.pdf]

Comment: @Wmmoreno link does not work...

Comment: @Lost1 , http://www.math.washington.edu/~morrow/334_10/thomae.pdf try to copy and paste, in you browser ... plz

Comment: ah the ] got included in the weblink, that is why

Comment: @Wmmoreno Thanks for that link but I don't find it helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint 1:**

If $x \in \mathbb Q$, you can find some sequence $x_n \in \mathbb R \setminus \mathbb Q$ such that $x_n \to x$.

Then $x_n \to x$ but $f(x_n)=0$ and $f(x) \neq 0$. What does this tell you?

**Hint 2:** If $x \notin \mathbb Q$.

Pick an $\epsilon >0$. Let $n$ be so that $\frac{1}{n+1} < \epsilon \leq \frac{1}{n}$.

Prove that there are only **finitely** many rational numbers $\frac{p}{q} \in (x-1,x+1)$ so that $q \leq n$.

Pick a such number $r$ which is closest to $x$ and let $\delta= \frac{|x-r|}{2}$.

Now, if $y \in (x- \delta,x+ \delta)$ what is $f(y)$? Note that you have two cases to cover: $y$ rational and $y$ irrational.

Answer (score 0):

The use of $\epsilon , \delta$ method is not the unique way to studying continuity of a function. You can use theorems of continuity such as " for a continuous function f if a sequence $\{a_n\}$ converges to $a$ then $\{f(a_n)\}$ converges to $f(a)$ . So you can choose a sequence  $\{a_n\}$ tending say $1$ then $f(a_n)$ is not convergent because it has tow subsequence with different limits. the subsequence of rationals tends to $1$ but for irrationals tends to $0$ then the function is discontinuous.